# How do I use the Firefox ping attribute?

Tags: firefox, attributes, ping

Firefox apparently supports a PING attribute for HREFs.  How do I implement code to receive the ping?

Comment: Looks like they removed it in Firefox 3 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support was disabled before the final release of Firefox 3, as Nissan Fan rightly states in comments. You can enable it via about:config by setting `browser.send_pings` to `true`, but the Firefox implementation differs from what currently is in specification.